# Use Ajax and Nodejs to update data on a page

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I am trying to write a loop to update a webpage every 30 seconds, but I am not sure how to make an ajax call with setInverval function. Here's my server code:

```
var app = express()
app.get('/', function(req, res){
// error here
res.sendFile('./index.html',{root: __dirname})
//...Some data 
res.send(data)
});
```

I have a setInverval function in my index.html:

```
<script>
function ajaxCall(){
  $.ajax({url: "http://localhost:3000/", success: function(result){
    // I want to receive new result every 30 seconds
  }})

}
setInterval(ajaxCall,30000)
</script>
```

Since I am not sure how to deal with app.get("/") and the ajax request, I got

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

cause I tried to send data twice

How should I modify the code so that I can see my data displaying on 'http://localhost:3000/' and it updates every 30 seconds?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Can't set headers after they are sent` usually indicates that *you respond to a request twice*.

You can't do that.

For each `request`/`req` there should only be one `response`/`res`.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // you respond to the request here
  res.sendFile('./index.html',{root: __dirname});
  // and you respond again here
  res.send(data)
});
```

Decide if you want to `sendFile()` OR `send(data)` for that endpoint.

Judging from your code you probably want to create *another* endpoint, to hit with your AJAX call, where it does the latter

```
// serve your index
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('./index.html',{root: __dirname})
});

// serve your data
// Your AJAX call should hit this endpoint instead
app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
  var data = 'lorem ipsum dolor';
  res.send(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I know that's a problem. If I want to send data and remove the sendFile(), my webpage will update everytime I refresh it but the setInterval function will never be called.

Answer (score 1):

Like Nicholas Kyriakides said, you need to define the following:

```
// serve your index
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('./index.html',{root: __dirname})
});

// serve your data
// Your AJAX call should hit this endpoint instead
app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
 var data = "lorem ipsum dolor";
  res.send(data);
});
```

Then, you need to change your AJAX call:

```
<script>
function ajaxCall(){
  $.ajax({url: "http://localhost:3000/data", success: function(result){
    //do whatever you want with the returned data (in result)
    //f.e. to update something on your web page, you want something like:
    document.getElementById("idOfElementYouWantChanged").innerHTML = result;
  }})

}
setInterval(ajaxCall,30000)
</script>
```

Comment: Apart from getting some magical internet points, what good does it do to blatantly copy/paste my answer?

Comment: I was already answering when I saw you answered as well, and it looked like he still did not understand the concept so I wanted to give him the full example. I'm sorry if I hurt your "magical internet points" feelings. I am only here to help.

Comment: Both answers helps, the Ajax call part does the trick, but since nicholas answered first ...

Comment: No problem, like I said I legitimately do not care :) good luck with whatever you are working on!